# Can I still complete the mission Mass Fusion after killing Elder Maxson?

Tags: fallout-4

I killed Elder Maxson before the Mass Fusion mission and now when I try to relay to Mass Fusion there is no prompt that asks me to be the Brotherhood's enemy (because I already am) so I am unable to teleport.

Can I still complete the mission Mass Fusion?

Comment: I really don't know. You could try walking there and seeing if the quest initiates. The [Mass fusion building](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Fusion_building) has an entrance on the ground floor at street level.

Comment: The Nukapedia page for the [Mass Fusion quest](http://fallout.wikia.com/wiki/Mass_Fusion#Bugs) has a bug listed that says you need to load a save from before betraying him, but only lists this bug for PlayStation.

Answer (score -3):

When I killed him on my first playthrough, it worked. But now on my second, it doesn't. So it sometimes works.

Comment: You tried it twice and got a different result each time. The scientific method demands more science than that unfortunately. As it stands now, either possibility could be an exception.