# No pop-up when relaying to Mass Fusion

Tags: fallout-4

I tried to relay to Mass Fusion from the Institute, but there is no pop-up, since I am already enemies with the Brotherhood of Steel, so it will not let me start the quest. I have no previous save point to go to. I'm about 40 hours in and I don't want to restart.

What are my options? Any patch to fix this? I'm playing on Xbox One.

Comment: Did you kill Elder Maxson already? http://gaming.stackexchange.com/q/247392/108003

Comment: Also, if you don't have save points to go back to, then lesson learned. Don't play a Bethesda game, especially on console, without making a lot of backup saves.

Comment: Oh wow, who doesn't save every couple minutes?  This reminds me of an acquaintance who played through most of Fallout 3 without knowing about encumbrance or fast travel.  That makes for a very slow, long game.

Answer (score 3):

Regrettably, you have likely encountered one of the many glitches in Fallout 4 - this one being more prohibitive than most. Referencing the wikia article for [Mass Fusion](https://fallout.fandom.com/wiki/Mass_Fusion) there is a glitch where you are unable to relay into Mass Fusion when you are enemies with the Brotherhood of Steel - which you are.

> If you betray the Brotherhood of Steel and are their enemy prior to beginning this quest, then you may not be able to relay out of the Institute. Fast traveling to Mass Fusion does not fix this, and you must load a save from before you were enemies with the BoS.[verified]

As the wikia article states, the only solution to this is to load a save game before becoming hostile to the Brotherhood.  As lamentable as it is, this a strong lesson in keeping multiple save states in Bethesda games.